# Setting variable type at run-time in Go

Tags: go

I have the following Go function which uses Gorm's `First()`:

```
func (r *SqlRepository) Get(id int, inventory any) (any, error) {
    result := db.First(&inventory, id)

    if result.Error != nil {
        var s struct{}
        return s, result.Error
    } else {
        return inventory, nil
    }
}
```

When calling that `Get` and passing an int and a struct created by me (`Get(1, model.InventoryToys{})`) I am getting

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value
```

From my understanding `any` means that that value can be anything so when I pass  `model.InventoryToys{}` that should become the type of `inventory`. Is that not how it works in Go? Am I missing something?

Just for context the reason I want it to be `any` is because I have multiple tables for inventory and multiple structs as a result and I didn't want to create a separate get function for each one of them to avoid code repetition. So essentially I am trying to dynamically assign the type of `inventory` to whatever is passed and let Gorm go and get data from the specified table.

Answer (score 2):

`any` is an interface that specified no methods, so all data types can be represented by `any`.

Go is a statically typed language, so you cannot set the type of a variable at runtime. The type of `inventory` is `any`. `inventory` can contain different values of different types. In your case, `inventory` contains a value of type `model.InventoryToys`. This is not a writable type, its address cannot be taken, because it is the copy of a value.

If you use `*model.InventoryToys`, then it becomes writable, because `inventory` now contains a pointer to a struct, and it can be written.

So, you have to set `inventory` to `&model.InventoryToys`, and pass `inventory` into `db.First`, and not `&inventory`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `Get` function as shown below.

```golang
func (r *SqlRepository) Get(id int, inventory any) (any, error) {
 result := db.First(inventory, id)
 if result.Error != nil {
  var s struct{}
  return s, result.Error
 } else {
  return inventory, nil
 }
}
```

You need to parse settable value to the `db.First` function. It should be a pointer of a model & shouldn't be a **pointer of an interface**. In side `gorm`, they use `reflection`. Refer [Laws of reflection](https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection) for more information.

You can call `Get` function as shown below.

```golang
 repo := SqlRepository{}
 id := 1
 toys := &model.InventoryToys{}
 repo.Get(id, &toys)
```

Comment: Isn't is supposed to be db.First(&inventory, id)?

Comment: Yes. Because the type of `&inventory` is an interface and it is not settable.